# C++11 regex: parse possible brackets

Tags: regex, c++11

I have a string that can be either of the form "X Y Z" where X,Y,Z are alphanumeric words separated by spaces, or "{ s1 } Y { s2 }" where s1,s2 are again a triple of words or containing brackets that contain another triples.  I can also have "{ s1 } Y Z" or "X Y { s2 }".

The rule is: the first or third word can contain another full triple inside curly braces.

I've been trying to come up with some regex-based recursive function that will return me the whole triple tree.

Will be glad for some advice.

Thanks!

=======

## EDIT

So I understood C++11 regex isn't good. Any ideas wrt boost regex? :)

Comment: Traditionally, regular expressions can't handle nested structures. There are extensions that might help, but regular expressions will probably still not be the best solution for nested structures. Also, using regular expression might instead [give you *two* problems](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems).

Comment: but i can detect only the outer brackets and continue recursively cant i?

Comment: You can match `{..}` with `\{.*?\}` to match, say, `{s1}` inside `{s1} X Z`, but if there are nested `{}`s, it will fail, e.g. `{s1 {s2}} X` as it will match `{s1 {s2}`. In C++11 you cannot use balancing constructs.

Comment: @TroyMcClure: C++ regex (which is derived from ECMA regex) doesn't have enough power to match arbitrarily nested brackets. C++ regex can only match up to a fixed level of nesting, and the regex is not pretty.

Comment: Regular expressions are not close to being [Turing complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) so no they can't do recursion.

Comment: From the comments so far I think you should try to parse it without regex. If you encounter problems too big for you, come back here, show us the code, and Stackoverflow will help you.